# Drawing hex tiles in Cocos2d for iOS

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to draw a hexagonal tile map. The TMX files they include is more heavyweight than simply the hex grid I need. I don't need images just a black/transparent background with the hex outline on top.

So far I have this:

```
CCTMXTiledMap *map = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"hexa-test.tmx"];
```

Is there a built-in routine or standard approach for doing this?

(I am new to cocos2d for iOS.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I've seen in Cocos2D, the tilemap is the only built-in way to draw a hex map. If you want anything else, you'll have to roll your own -- but I don't think it's going to be all that difficult to do.

Try [this page](http://www.rdwarf.com/lerickson/hex/index.html) for info on a basic hex drawing algorithm.

There's also [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/hexagonal_part1.aspx) which draws many hexagons in a map.

Hope that helps.
Mike

Comment: Sorry for getting back to this so late. Thanks for your answer.